# How can I call jQuery after show extjs window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, window

I have an ExtJS window:

```
screenshotWindow = new Ext.Window({bla bla});
```

Opening it all right:

```
screenshotWindow.show();
```

I need to call a jQuery method after loading a window.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    debugger;
    $("#imageAnn").annotateImage({
        editable: true,
        useAjax: false,
    });
});
```

How/where can I do that? All of this code above happens in my ExtJS controller. Is itemID correct to reference into from method?

```
var changingImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: '/images/trafalgar-square-annotated.jpg',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    itemID: 'imageAnn',
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use JQuery combined with ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ExtJS but it appears that you would do...

```
screenshotWindow.show(this, function(){
  $("#imageAnn").annotateImage({
    editable: true,
    useAjax: false,
  });
});
```

based on this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/window/layout.html

Answer (score 3):

Each ExtJS component has a set of events you can listen for:

```
screenshotWindow = new Ext.Window({
  // ...
  listeners: {
    show: function() {
      // anything you want to do after this component is displayed
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to perform some action after the application is loaded, you can use `Ext.onReady()`:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  // app has been loaded and is ready to use
});
```

---

I'd generally advise against mixing jQuery and ExtJS since they follow different paradigms and operate on different abstraction levels. Needing jQuery in an ExtJS app usually means you're doing something wrong (unless you depend on some highly specialised jQuery plugin...)